# How to make PyCharm remember Google AppEngine's oAuth2 credentials?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, pycharm

When deploying GAE apps PyCharm is using the following command:

```
appcfg.py --oauth2 --no_cookies update .
```

The **--no_cookies** parameter according to appcfg.py prevents it from saving the oAuth credentials:

```
  --no_cookies          Do not save authentication cookies to local disk.
```

How do I disable/remove/change that parameter since every time I am deploying an app PyCharm is asking for authorization and while doing it just via appcfg.py works perfectly fine.

Thanks!

Comment: I created a "Usability Problem" issue here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13846 for this question but there's no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a shortcoming of PyCharm that it always uses the `--no_cookies` option.  I agree there should be an option to let it store cookies, especially with oauth.  The new Cloud SDK lets you sign in once and run `appcfg.py` without arguments to reuse the login, but it looks like PyCharm won't let you do that either.  It'd be great if PyCharm could be updated to interact with the new SDK.

You can add an item to PyCharm's Tools menu to run an arbitrary command, including the correct deployment command.  Under Preferences, select Editor: External Tools.  Click the `+` button to add a tool.

- Name: Deploy to AE
- Program: `google-cloud-sdk/bin/appcfg.py`
- Parameters: `update --oauth2 $ProjectFileDir$`

And make sure the appropriate "Show in" checkboxes are checked.  Click OK to dismiss the dialog, then OK to close preferences.  You should now have a "Deploy to AE" item in the Tools menu.

If you want to use the Cloud SDK's built-in auth management, sign in via `gcloud`:

```
gcloud auth login
```

Then remove the `--oauth2` argument from the Parameters.

The `gcloud` command is from the latest Cloud SDK.  You can get it from here: https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/

You use the `gcloud` command to install the App Engine SDK and other components, including the `appcfg.py` command.  You can tell PyCharm to use the SDK that it installs by providing the SDK path `google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine` (where `google-cloud-sdk` is where you installed it).

Comment: I guess that works. Not exactly what I wanted although this did give me an idea to simply create a new sub-menu item next to the original "Upload App Engine App..." which would simply run the proper command instead of the incorrect one. Not sure if that would allow me to see the upload logs though the way they are shown now but I'll work on it when I get a chance. Thanks! ( _P.S. looking forward to your new GAE Python book!_ )

Comment: Thanks!  I was wondering if PyCharm let you extend the menus.  It looks like this is Preferences: Editor: External Tools.  Program: `google-cloud-sdk/bin/appcfg.py`, Parameters: `update $Projectpath$`  That works for me.  It also knows to pop open an output window.  Cool!

Comment: Edited the answer to fold in the custom menu item idea. Glad that this works!

Comment: Install the App Engine SDK with: `gcloud components update gae-python`